# How the add_action is included in the plugin development

Tags: plugin-development

In the plugin development, why can we use the `add_action` function (and other WordPress functions) without `require`/`include` the `wp-includes/plugin.php`? I'm sure they have been included. Where and how are those functions included?

Comment: Did you search through the source files? Somewhere [in these results](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/search?l=PHP&q=plugin.php) you should find the include.

Comment: It's loaded by wp-load, and generally you can just assume all of WordPress core that you'll need is loaded. Or you can check: you'll see a lot of existing code abort if ABSPATH isn't defined, which the first variable set up by the load process.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I think I've found it in `wp-settings.php`.